# Resize image to fit div works but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://jcl.juplo.com/map/) I'm creating, for some reason the image is full size in Firefox, but it correctly resizes to fit Chrome and other browsers.
I have no idea why this isn't working in Firefox.
Does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Here is my css:

```css
#map-wrap {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#map {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#space-holder {
    width: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#map-options {
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#map img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `max-width: 100%` to `width: 100%` or just use both.