# How to get multiple images to auto resize and stay centered within a div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, image-resizing

I am trying to get the multiple university logo images in a row to scale down as the browser width gets smaller and not overflow its container div, just like I do with the blueish picture above. The picture scales within its div by applying max width and heigh of 100%. But the logo images do not scale in the same way and overflow the div.

Here is a live example: http://feroze.org/new-education/ - try resizing and see what I mean

Here is the css for the logos container div gray bar

```
#partners
  height 105px
  background-color #eee
  white-space nowrap
  width 100%
```

and here is the css applied to the logo images themselves

```
.logo-image
  vertical-align middle
  padding 13px
  max-width 100%
  display inline
```

As you can see I aligned them vertically in the grey bar. But as the bar shortens I want the images to stay within the div and resize according to the container div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

[image: screenshot of logo overflow]

Comment: mind sharing website URL or creating a Fiddle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure what HTML you've already got, but if the images are each wrapped inside a `<div>` or `<li>` then you can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell` to ensure that no matter how many images, they'll always fit the width correctly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#partners {
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #eee;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 13px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="partners">
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working demo here](http://jsbin.com/Acexuhu/1/edit).

Comment: OMG! Thanks so much, I was playing around with this for sometime and I couldn't get it but this worked flawlessly! I am so happy thank you very much. I searched stack overflow many times and I couldn't find a a question or answer that resolved this problem. Your the best, if I could upvote multiple times I would thanks

Comment: ah although this doesnt work in firefox. Do you know a fix for firefox?

Comment: I figured it out in firefox. just needed to add width 100% to .logo-image img See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970591/resize-image-to-fit-div-works-but-not-in-firefox

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to do this:

First, you can set the max-width to 100%/number of images (in this case six).
box-sizing is a new CSS attribute that contains the padding inside the width.

So you can set the padding to whatever you want, but if you have box-sizing set to border-box and a hard-coded width, the width will never change (unless you have overflow, of course).

```
box-sizing: border-box;
max-width: 16%;
```

Second, you can use the new CSS function calc(). We subtract 26px because of the 13px of padding on each side.

```
max-width: calc(100% / 6 - 26px);
```

Lastly, you can use calc() and box-sizing, preventing the need to subtract 26px.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
max-width: calc(100% / 6);
```