# Multiple image scaling CSS IE fix?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, image-resizing, autoresize

I've used the fix in this question to resize images in one single line and it works perfectly, that is until you get into IE then IE just decides to ignore it completely. Does anyone have a fix?

Here's what I used:

[How to get multiple images to auto resize and stay centered within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896626/how-to-get-multiple-images-to-auto-resize-and-stay-centered-within-a-div)

Here's the page I'm working on in Chrome:

[Chrome Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBGiK.png)

Here's the page I'm working on in IE:

[IE Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjJmG.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this happen on full screen or when resizing the browser. Also what happen on chrome when resizing the browser

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? And what internet explorer version are you using?